# "col-md-6" is not working when i am trying to place two div's next to each other

Tags: responsive-design

I am trying to place text part and image next to each other with bootstrap classes but couldn't. Please help.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="home-shape">

        <div class="col-md-6">
          <h1>Find Your Perfect Future Home</h1>
          <p>Search confidentially with your trusted source of homes for sale or rent</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-6 home-image-banner">
          <img src="images/building.png" alt="">
        </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Q: What happens if you remove the <p>..</p> tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `col-md-6` needs to be an immediate child of the `row`. If you need the `home-shape` class, change the code to: `<div class="row home-shape">`, instead of separate `divs`.